# Is it possible to programmatically bind two key paths setting continuous updates in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstablecolumn

In a macOS Cocoa Application if I have two NSSlider objects, I can set the following binding programmatically:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstSlider: NSSlider!
@IBOutlet weak var secondSlider: NSSlider!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    self.firstSlider.bind(NSBindingName.init(rawValue: "value"), to: self.secondSlider, withKeyPath: "value", options: [NSBindingOption.continuouslyUpdatesValue : true])
}
```

This works, but not continuously updating, unless I set the Continuous checkbox in the inspector in interface builder for the sliders. My problem is that I would like to set the binding between other properties that do not expose a continuous setting by themselves, specifically two NSTableColumn instances. Is it possible to bind continuously by setting an option in the binding code?

Comment: "My problem is that I would like to set the binding between other properties that do not expose a continuous setting by themselves, specifically two NSTableColumn instances." What do you mean by this, exactly? The "continuous" option for a slider makes it so that it updates bindings whenever its moved, rather than only updating when it's "let go". `NSTableColumn` wouldn't have any counterpart to that

Comment: I am trying to keep two NSOutlineView objects in perfect sync. So I am interested in the "width" keypath of two NSTableColumn objects. I am currently solving the problem by using KVO and updates are delivered continuously. By using programmatic bindings I was hoping to achieve a cleaner implementation. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Ah, that's some key information, I think you should edit it into your question. IDK if those fields supporting binding. If they don't, I'd just recommend to us RxSwift/RxCocoa, which present a single unified stream interface over KVO, NSBinding, NSNotificationCenter, delegates, and closure callbacks

Comment: Without digging into this problem, I suspect it would be far easier to create a `float` property on your controller, then bind both of the slider's to this property (no programming required). Any change in one slider will update the property, which will change the other slider. Remember to set the "continuous" attribute of the value binding.

Comment: “currently solving the problem by using KVO and updates are delivered continuously. By using programmatic bindings I was hoping to achieve a cleaner implementation.” Sort of a distinction without a difference. Cocoa bindings _are_ KVO.

Comment: @matt: Bindings certainly makes heavy use of KVO (and indeed KVO/KVC was introduced to support Bindings), but Bindings builds significant additional functionality on top of KVO. And while it's an implementation detail, there are significant parts of bindings functionality that could be implemented in terms of (public/standard) KVO, but are in fact not. To OP's point, using bindings vs. "programmatic KVO" can mean writing significantly less code, which is surely what he's trying to achieve, and which is basically the whole point of bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, this is not possible. You should just use your own KVO code as you've already discovered.

Longer answer follows:

Fundamentally, the issue is two fold: `NSTableColumn` does not have a [`continuous`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428952-iscontinuous#) property. There are classes that do (e.g. `NSControl` and `NSCell`), but `NSTableColumn` doesn't inherit from these. Technically, this property is meant to determine whether a control sends its *action method to its target* continuously, rather than specifically being about bindings, though it does also affect binding behavior.

The [`.continuouslyUpdatesValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbindingoption/1458082-continuouslyupdatesvalue#) binding option means something slightly different. It is used to determine whether bound value is updated continuously during user interaction or only when the UI element resigns its responder status (ie. user interaction stops). This is mostly useful for text field/view bindings.

Unfortunately, `NSTableColumn` can't *really* be a responder, at least in the traditional sense. And this option has no effect on bindings from an `NSTableColumn`'s `width`.

Confusingly, this option *also* has no effect on bindings from `NSSlider`. Instead, if `NSSlider`'s `continuous` property is `false`, it will always only update the binding on mouse up, *even if* the `.continuouslyUpdatesValue` option is set on the binding. Conversely, if `NSSlider`'s `continuous` property is `true`, it will always update the binding's value continuously, *even if* the `.continuouslyUpdatesValue` option is set to false on the binding.

Some digging with the debugger explains this behavior. `NSSlider` always updates its bindings value as a side effect of sending its action to its target (regardless of the `.continuouslyUpdatesValue` option). This explains why its `continuous` property solely determines its behavior.

On the other hand, while `NSTableColumn` updates its `width` **property** and thus emits KVO notifications continuously as its width is changed, it only updates its `width` **binding** as a side effect of posting the [`columnDidResizeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1526315-columndidresizenotification) that it posts on width changes. This notification is only ever posted at the end of a resize, not during a resize. Thus, `NSTableColumn` only ever updates its binding at the end of a resize.